# Swift Firebase how to stop proccess?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var btnMenu: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var txtMessage: UILabel!

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

var storage = FIRStorage.storage()

var storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL("gs://...")
```

@IBAction func actionLoad(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    var count : Int?
    var fileName : String?

   let imageRef = self.rootRef.child("users").child(LoginViewController.USER_ID!).child("images").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        count = snapshot.value! as! Int


        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image1.image!, 0.8)!

        if count == 0 {
            fileName = "1.jpg"
        }else if count == 1 {
            fileName = "2.jpg"
        }else if count == 2 {
            fileName = "3.jpg"
        }else if count == 3 {
            fileName = "4.jpg"
        }else if count == 4 {
            fileName = "5.jpg"
        }
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        if count < 5 {

            self.storageRef.child(LoginViewController.USER_ID!).child(fileName!).putData(data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
                if let error = error {

                    self.txtMessage.text = error.localizedDescription

                }else{

                    self.txtMessage.text = "Your picture uploaded"
                    self.rootRef.child("users").child(LoginViewController.USER_ID!).child("images").setValue(count!+1)

                }

            }

        }else{
            self.txtMessage.text = "Sorry, you may to upload maximum 5 photos"

        }

    })

}
```

how to stop? it continues until count == 5. but don't want a loop proccess. after click it should upload one picture and stop! i tried :
"rootRef.removeAllObservers" but not sure about how to use it

Comment: please add more details on whats exactly you are trying to do. I cant see whats your currently problem.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the button "actionLoad" the function checking how many pictures are already uploaded and if less than 5 picture then the function upload picture that the user chose. But the the problem that by one clicking the button the function doesnt stop and contunues to upload that  picture again and again until 5 uploaded.